# How do I support variable screen ratios using AndEngine?

Tags: android, andengine, resolution, aspect-ratio

When displaying a background, AndEngine produces black bars above the image on certain devices.  How do I support variable screen ratios for different devices using AndEngine?

Comment: Can you clarify this a bit?

Comment: i am getting a black screen on top of my 9 patch image.When i run my code. In my small size device this image working well but when i am using tablet it display with some black screen on top of this image.I want to use this one image in different size of screen. All devices must be supported.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe what you're asking is how to get rid of letterboxing, like this:

[image]

By default, AndEngine assumes you want some fixed aspect ratio.  It then uses letterboxing to handle devices with different display aspect ratios then what you're providing.  The advantage is you have certainty about your layout.

There's more than one approach to get rid of them, but here's what I do.  The following code takes a fixed height (in this case 320) and adjusts the width based on the aspect ratio of the device.

```
//Pick some value for your height.
float cameraHeight = 320;

//Get the display metrics object.
final DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();

//Populate it with data about your display.
this.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);

//Calculate the aspect ratio ofthe device.
float aspectRatio = (float) displayMetrics.widthPixels / (float) displayMetrics.heightPixels;

//Multiply the aspect ratio by the fixed height.
float cameraWidth = Math.round(aspectRatio * CAMERA_HEIGHT);

//Create the camera using those values.
this.mCamera = new Camera(0, 0, cameraWidth, cameraHeight);
```

Comment: Not on both side blank (top and Bottom) but only on top side i am getting blank screen.

Comment: @Maan Nonetheless, does this resolve it?  Also, might help if you post a screenshot.

Comment: sorry ,i cant' send you screen shots as a image because i have only 2 reputation.

Comment: i am trying to implement the code which you give n to me but what is GameConstant. I am getting red mark on that line.

Comment: ya it's accepted

Comment: You are genius good calculation about camera you did. I first use CroppedResolutionPolicy but the height of the sprite become improper in that. I up vote you answer. I need your suggestion for this. By using this calculation If I put sprite on 100,100 then it will display on same position on all the resolution or not? I eagerly wait for your reply.

Comment: @Siddharth 100,100 will always be the same location relative to the top left corner,but what will vary is how much space you have to the right.

Comment: If I create level for 1024x768 resolution then it create same look for all other resolution or not? I need this information.

Comment: Using this method I create level select screen then it will generate different space in right hand side area of device. Starting position is same for every resolution but generated right hand side area is different per new resolution. So please know me how to handle this?

Comment: @Siddharth, generally the way AndEngine works is you specify a set resolution to build to and it will scale it to whatever device (and add letterbox where the aspect ratio differs).  What I described above is an alternative behavior, which avoids the letterboxing effect, but does so at the price that you don't have the same aspect ratio universally.  You can't have both (unless you're willing to stretch).

Comment: @CameronFredman so what to do in this situation? I found other solution as well. http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/2073/how-would-you-handle-different-aspect-ratios-in-a-2d-platformer?rq=1 Do you have any experience with this? Please share you ideas because you small thought become important for me.

Comment: @Siddharth It really is a strategic decision you have to make for your particular game.  I tend to think, for something like a RTS, it's nice to just show more area of the map.  For a platformer, it might make sense to use letterboxing.  It really is your own design decision.

Comment: sorry for my more question. please suggest me on this also http://www.andengine.org/forums/gles2/graphics-and-camera-strategy-t11426.html

Answer (score 1):

I used CropResolutionPolicy, a [new policy developed](http://www.andengine.org/forums/gles2/targeting-multiple-display-resolutions-t6794.html#p29955) and later [further extended](http://android.kul.is/2013/10/andengine-tutorial-dealing-with-screen-sizes.html) by members of the AndEngine community. Crop policy is similar to Ratio that comes with the AndEngine, but instead of padding, it scales the scene while keeping aspect ratio to cover the whole screen and crops the overflow.

Crop policy is illustrated on the following image from [this website that explains all the AndEngine resolution policies](http://android.kul.is/2013/10/andengine-tutorial-dealing-with-screen-sizes.html).

[image]
*image used with permission of the author*

Comment: This would be a better answer if it summarized the techniques explained in the link.